# Bolt size for the Weerider Kangaroo

Tags: child-seat, children

I lost the main bolt for a [Weerider Kangaroo,](http://www.weeride.com/Kangaroo-Center-Mounted-Child-Bicycle-Carrier) just wondering if someone has one and can tell me the size of the main bolt the one that attaches the seat to the bar.

[image]

Comment: http://www.weeride.com/Contact says "for parts and service contact..." suggesting that they do offer replacement parts.

Answer (score 1):

I would urge you to check online, and order a replacement from WeeRide. Parts like this are hardened more than standard hardware grade steel.

If this was a reflector screw, then I'd say grab anything from the local hardware store. However, in this case there's a lot more at stake and you don't wanna cut corners.

I have no experience with WeeRide, but I have gotten replacement parts from other companies sent to me, free of charge, when I inquired online.

http://www.weeride.com/Kangaroo-Center-Mounted-Child-Bicycle-Carrier

Comment: Thanks I did this already, but while I am waiting for a reply I am looking at a plan B :) yes cutting corners is definitely not an option.

Comment: This thing is for holding a toddler. I doubt that they used any special steel for the fasteners. But if you are worried about it, go to an auto parts store. The bolts and nuts sold there tend to be more sturdy.

Comment: Whichever store you go to, you should be able to to determine the type and strength of steel used by [looking at the markings](https://www.boltdepot.com/fastener-information/Materials-and-Grades/Bolt-Grade-Chart.aspx) on the bolt.

Comment: Any decent fastening supplier will have a range of hardnesses available for most bolts. Or be able to get them. And there's a lot more to selecting the hardness than "more important = harder steel". And @Kibbee ... not if they've lost the bolt.

Comment: In the interim, while you're waiting on parts, just bring the Kangaroo into the hardware store to find a match.